# Import data from a webpage

Tags: r, encoding, httr

I am using the following code:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
sess <- html_session("http://www.bh.com.tn/", 
                      user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.39 Safari/537.36"))
pg <- jump_to(sess, "http://www.bh.com.tn/devise.asp")
dat <- content(pg$response, as="parsed")
```

I get the following error:

> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.

When I use the url in the browser it works fine. So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it an error or a warning? Is `dat` empty?

Comment: i don't know is it error or warning it appears like this when i execute this code: dat <- content(pg$response, as="parsed")                                          I think dat is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning. If you specify the encoding parameter, there's no warning:

```
content(pg$response, as="parsed", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: I execute that code:                                                                                            dat = html_table(html_nodes(dat, "table")[[2]], header=TRUE)                         error message appears:                                                                                          Error : Table has inconsistent number of columns. Do you want fill = TRUE?

Comment: You can specify the fill argument in html_table as TRUE, but the resulting dataframe looks messy to me.

html_table currently makes a few assumptions: (1) no cells span multiple rows, (2) headers are in the first row. Are you sure the table has no cells spanning multiple rows?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. Here you can check the table.                                                              http://www.bh.com.tn/devise.asp

Comment: There are many row- and colspans actually. Check the source: htmlParse(html_nodes(dat, "table")[[2]])

Comment: thank you Rool, I installed two package "rvest" and "httr", and when I execute  the code you have send me. I obtained this error: Can 't find the function"htmlParse".

Comment: htmlParse is part of the XML package.

Comment: You don't need the XML package to scrape the table though. Just specify which table you want to scrape by using Xpath:  

`read_html(pg) %>% html_nodes(xpath="//div[@class='CorpsDeTexte']/table[1]") %>% html_table()`